# High center brake light polarity reversed?

Tags: brakes, lights, bulbs

My center brake light's polarity is unusual: the side sleeve of the bulb gets +12V and the dot at the bottom (electrical contact) gets 0V ground. All the other fittings (brake lights, reversing lights, blinkers) are the opposite. I thought the sleeve always gets the ground, did I miss something? Is it normal for the third brake light to be reversed in polarity? (halogen bulbs obviously)

Comment: What is the vehicle in question? (year/make/model)

Comment: Is there any sign of any repair work around the interior mount for the CHMSL? It could be that someone pulled it out for some reason and wired it backwards when they reinstalled it.

Comment: @FreeMan No obvious signs to note. Please don't interpret my post as a problem to solve - it is not. It's a genuine question whether you have ever seen anything like this, or if anyone knows a common reason as to why it could be OEM or incorrect installation.

Comment: @Dan - Some lights in some cars are wired backwards for whatever reason the manufacturer has decided to do that. I'm not sure the reason. If you give me the information I asked for, we could do some searching to see if your specific vehicle is done that way or if there is something jenky.

Comment: If you don't have an actual problem to solve, but are just looking for discussion, then you run afoul of the [on-topic](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) requirements that state that you shouldn't ask if "there is no actual problem to be solved", or if "you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question". Without the vehicle details and without a definite problem to solve, I'd VtC if I had the rep...

Comment: @FreeMan I am sorry to have ignored the topic requirements, you are right. I don't mind this topic being closed as Paulster2 has already given me an answer.